# Split requests to subdomain to 2 ports

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, port

I have a subdomain on an Apache web server that contains 2 folders: frontend and backend. My frontend is running a node application, whereas my backend has a headless CMS. I have both of these running on different ports.

How can I set up my .htaccess so that, for example, requests to subdomain.domain.com go to the frontend whereas some specific ones such as subdomain.domain.com/admin go to the backend?

Comment: Do you have access to **Apache**'s main configuration or **<VirtualHost>** configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, actually. First, enable some Apache modules with the following commands:

```
$ sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Modify your configuration, so it looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # A lot of directives come here...
    ProxyPassPreserve On

    <Location /frontend>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
    </Location>

    <Location /backend>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8001/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8001/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart or reload your Apache service with:

```
$ sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stefano! Seems like that could be a good fix, hadn't seen mention of the <Location> before. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get any of those commands to work. I've ssh'd into my server and whether I run a2enmod, systemctl, mod_rewrite, jailshell keeps telling me "command not found". Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Phil, these commands are used in Debian-based Linux distributions, like Ubuntu. If you're using other distribution, like Fedora, CentOS, etc. you should use similar commands, like `yum` for package management, for instance. Also, as far as I remember, the Apache module management is a little bit different, even if the logic and the Apache configuration remains the same. I'm not familiar with jailshell, unfortunately. :(

Comment: No worries Stefano. I'll play around with this and come back to accept your answer when I can get it working :)